# Stencil unit test: access deeply nested Shadow DOM components

Tags: ionic-framework, jestjs, stenciljs

I have a `Stencil.js` component library with some nested elements that I'm unit testing

I'm using the `newSpecPage` helper functionality provided by Stencil:

```js
const page = await newSpecPage({
    components: [CustomFileInput, CustomPanel],
    html: `
      <custom-file-input multiple>                    
      </custom-file-input>
    `
});
```

The `CustomPanel` component is nested within the `CustomFileInput` component. To query elements within `CustomPanel` I have to step down through `Shadow DOM` elements before being able to run a `querySelector()` command successfully

```js
// page.root is the CustomFileInput HTML Element
const customPanelElement = page.root.shadowRoot.querySelector('custom-panel');
const queriedElemnt = customPanelElement.shadowRoot.querySelector('panel-child')
```

I'm wondering is there a more concise way to get a reference to the `CustomPanel` or `panel-child` elements rather than querying down through the components? In the above case there's just 2 components, but there could be more of course

Answer (score 1):

I presume you are using `shadow:true` so you have to use `page.root.shadowRoot.querySelector('custom-panel')`

What you can do is, you can assign reference inside `beforeEach` block

```
   const customPanelElement;
   const queriedElemnt;
   const page;

   beforeEach(async () => {
    page = await newSpecPage({
    components: [CustomFileInput, CustomPanel],
    html: `
      <custom-file-input multiple>                    
      </custom-file-input>
    `,
      supportsShadowDom: true
    });
    //Create reference here so that it is available inside every test case
    customPanelElement = page.root.shadowRoot.querySelector('custom-panel');
    queriedElemnt = customPanelElement.shadowRoot.querySelector('panel-child')
  });
```